# Is it possible to make full screen modal with html dialog element?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I am attempting to create full screen menu using `dialog` element and css.
My trials so far lead to following style code (on top of css reset).

```css
dialog {
    padding: revert;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Only this ensures that there will be no huge gap around modal window. But it has 2 problems that prevent normal positioning of children:

- mandatory 16px padding
- mandatory 3px border

Neither can be removed without reintroducing mentioned huge gap around modal. The only way I found to hide border is to assign background color to it.

```css
dialog {
    background-color: salmon;
    border-color: salmon;
}
```

However, in the end contents of this modal are displaced by 19px from each side.

Are there better solutions to fix it and make modal `dialog` take exactly whole viewport?

Comment: Yes, it actually does. Strange, searching did not bring this page up.